# Big-Oh: Is f(n) = 3^n in O(g(n)) = 10^n?

Tags: math, big-o, complexity-theory

I can prove this, but I don't conceptually understand why 3^n is in O(10^n). Am I wrong?

Comment: `3^n` is in `O(10^n)` because it doesn't grow asymptotically faster than `10^n`. That's not a tight bound of course. `3^n` is also in `O(3^n)` which is a tight bound.

Comment: `h(n) = 1` and `i(n) = n` are also both in `O(10^n)`

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, the larger the base of the exponent, the faster the growth of the function.

Big-O gives us an upper bound; that is, given two functions `f(n)` and `g(n)`, if for all values of `n` above a certain threshold (barring some minor details like the constant multiple), `g(n)` dominates `f(n)`, then we can say that `f(n) = O(g(n))`.

Now, for any `n >= 0`, it should be clear that `10^n` is at least as large (but most of the time much larger) than `3^n`.

Note that it's not particularly useful to say that `3^n = O(10^n)`. This isn't a tight bound by any means; the growth rates of these two functions are drastically different. A more effective bound for `3^n` is itself — that is to say, `3^n = O(3^n)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I figured, because the bound isn't "tight", I was getting confused if it was considered o(g(n)) at all! I just wanted to confirm that it would still be correct, even if it is not useful.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed correct, but not useful. We could also say that `1 = O(10^n)`. While this is true, it's *really* not useful; an order 1 function has constant runtime while an order `10^n` function has exponentially worse runtime.

Comment: @MH1993 Note that you should be careful when writing with `o` (little-oh) vs `O` (big-oh). They mean two different things, `o` means the bound definitely isn't tight, `O` means it may or may not be. `o` is to `<` what `O` is to `<=`.